# Python equivalent of Ruby's each_with_index?

Tags: python, ruby, equivalent

In Ruby, if I have an array and I want to use both the indexes and the values in a loop, I use `each_with_index`.

```
a=['a','b','c']
a.each_with_index{|v,i| puts("#{i} : #{v}") }
```

prints

```
0 : a 
1 : b
2 : c
```

What is the Pythonic way to do the same thing?

Comment: [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like:

```
for i, v in enumerate(a):
   print "{} : {}".format(i, v)
```

Answer (score 4):

That'd be [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
a=['a','b','c']
for i,v in enumerate(a):
    print "%i : %s" % (i, v)
```

Prints

```
0 : a
1 : b
2 : c
```